# How to get marginalized Fokker-Planck equation for the time-dependent Gaussian velocity distribution?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, diffusion, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have come across the term "Marginalized Fokker-Planck equation! ", which I have never heard of and could not find any resource online. The equation reads as following
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} P(x,v,t) = -  \left( \frac{\partial} {\partial x}v + \frac{\partial} {\partial v} \left[  - \frac{\gamma}{m}v - \frac{\gamma k_{B}T}{m^{2}} \frac{\partial}{\partial v} \right] \right) P(x,v,t)
$$
where $P(x,v,t)$ is the Gaussian distribution
$$
P(v,t) = \frac{1} {\sqrt{2\pi \Sigma (t)}} exp \left( -\frac{(v - \mu (t))^{2}}{2\Sigma (t)} \right)
$$
How to solve this equation and what does "Marginalized Fokker-Planck" equation stands for? Does someone ever heard of this? Thanks!!

Comment: Without further context it's difficult to say for certain, but P(v,t) is a marginal distribution of the full joint distribution of P(x, v, t). Easiest way to see that P(v, t) is indeed Gaussian is probably to write the PDE as an SDE.